# custom function with non-standard evaluation (behaves like Table)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like a function `AnyTrue[expr,{i,{i1,i2,...}}]` which checks if `expr` is `True` for any of `i1,i2...` It should be as if `AnyTrue` was `Table` followed by `Or@@%`, with the difference that it only evaluates `expr` until first `True` is found.

Short-circuiting part is optional, what I'd really like to know is the proper way to emulate `Table`'s non-standard evaluation sequence.

**Update 11/14**

Here's a solution due to Michael, you can use it to chain "for all" and "there exists" checks

```
SetAttributes[AllTrue, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[AnyTrue, HoldAll];
AllTrue[{var_Symbol, lis_List}, expr_] := 
  LengthWhile[lis, 
    TrueQ[ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[var] -> #]] &] == 
   Length[lis];
AnyTrue[{var_Symbol, lis_List}, expr_] := 
  LengthWhile[lis, 
    Not[TrueQ[ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[var] -> #]]] &] < 
   Length[lis];
AllTrue[{a, {1, 3, 5}}, AnyTrue[{b, {2, 4, 5}}, EvenQ[a + b]]]
AnyTrue[{a, {1, 3, 5}}, AllTrue[{b, {2, 4, 5}}, EvenQ[a + b]]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
SetAttributes[AnyTrue, HoldAll];

AnyTrue[expr_, {var_Symbol, lis_List}] :=
  LengthWhile[lis, 
    Not[TrueQ[ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[var] -> #]]] &
  ] < Length[lis]
```

Includes short-circuiting via `LengthWhile` and keeps everything held where necessary so that things work as expected with `var` has a value outside the function:

```
In[161]:= x = 777;

In[162]:= AnyTrue[Print["x=", x]; x == 3, {x, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]
During evaluation of In[162]:= x=1
During evaluation of In[162]:= x=2    
During evaluation of In[162]:= x=3
Out[162]= True
```

The built-in `Or` is short-circuiting, too, for what it's worth. (but I realize building up the unevaluated terms with e.g. `Table` is a pain):

```
In[173]:= Or[Print[1];True, Print[2];False]
During evaluation of In[173]:= 1
Out[173]= True
```

Comment: coming late, I'd just point out that excessive details in argument patterns do not often go well with Hold attributes. For example, the following call fails: AnyTrue[i < 10, {i, Range[5]}], while in principle it should not (the pattern does not match since at the pattern-matching time it does not know that Range[5] is List). This slightly more general signature will remove this problem: AnyTrue[expr_, {var_Symbol, lis_}]. Also, AnyTrue doesn't work in M8 on packed lists - there seems to be a bug in LengthWhile: LengthWhile[Range[5], ! TrueQ[# < 10] &] gives 5, am going to report it.

Comment: Yes, good point Leonid. It would be better to have a more general pattern and validate the argument after evaluating it. `HoldAll` instead of `HoldFirst` is necessary since we want to keep `var` held in addition to `expr`, otherwise there wouldn't be an issue with the more discerning pattern.

Comment: @Leonid -- I have just noticed the comment about PackedArray bug, and I wish I saw it earlier!..."@Yaroslav" would send notification to me, whereas Michael is notified automatically since comment is on his answer  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71903/add-a-comment-syntax-help-when-writing-a-comment

Comment: @Yaroslav - Sorry, I thought the owner of the question is notified automatically. I should learn this SO mechanics better! Anyway, I wrote a similar function myself for my own uses a while ago, that one does not rely on LengthWhile and should be fine (but it suffers from the same pattern-matching problem as Michael's - could be fixed in principle) - see my reply to your post.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't match your spec but I often use the following utility functions, which are similar to what you have in mind (they use pure functions instead of expressions with a specified variable) and also do short-circuiting:

```
some[f_, l_List] := True ===                (* Whether f applied to some      *)
  Scan[If[f[#], Return[True]]&, l];         (*  element of list is True.      *)

every[f_, l_List] := Null ===               (* Similarly, And @@ f/@l         *)
  Scan[If[!f[#], Return[False]]&, l];       (*  (but with lazy evaluation).   *)
```

For example, Michael Pilat's example would become this:

```
In[1]:= some[(Print["x=", #]; # == 3)&, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

   During evaluation of In[1]:= x=1
   During evaluation of In[1]:= x=2    
   During evaluation of In[1]:= x=3
Out[1]= True
```

Comment: Useful trick. Note, using "If" instead of "TrueQ" requires a bit more care with syntax, ie `every[False, {a, {1, 3, 5}}]` gives "True"

Comment: You had me worried at first but I don't think there's a bug here.  Note that the first argument needs to be a function.  `every[False&, {1,3,5}]` works as expected.

Comment: Right, no bug, just a subtle semantic difference, since it's "True" if f evaluates to "something other than False" for every element of the list