# how to use sort function the same way as max or min in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Please take a look at the following code:

```
Sort[{1, y, x}, Greater]
Max[{1, x, y}]
x = 1
y = 2
Sort[{1, y, x}, Greater]
Max[{1, x, y}]
```

It is interesting to note that the first Sort always produce a definite result while the first Max does not, even when Greater is specified. Note I have not given any numerical values for x and y. Why is this and how can I have a Sort function behave the same way as the Max (or Min) function?

Thanks!

BTW, I am using Mma 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help:

```
Sort orders symbols by their names, and in the event of a tie, by their context
```

So, what you want is another function, not Sort[] ...

**Edit**

Here is a way to force only numerical sort under your premises:

```
sortN[s_, f_: (OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &)] :=

 (*Check if everything is eval to a number*)
 If[And @@ (NumericQ /@ s),

  (*and then sort*)
  Sort[s, f],

  (*if something not numeric,
  reconstruct the function call and return it*)
  If[(ToString[f] == ToString[OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &]), 
    Print[Unevaluated[sortN[s]]], Print[Unevaluated[sortN[s, f]]]];]
```

Usage:

```
In[120]:= sortN[{3,2,1,4}]
Out[120]= {1,2,3,4}

In[121]:= sortN[{3,2,1,Sin}]
Out[121]= sortN[{3,2,1,Sin}]

In[122]:= sortN[{1,2,3,4},Greater]
Out[122]= {4,3,2,1}

In[123]:= sortN[{1,2,3,Log},Greater]
Out[123]= sortN[{1,2,3,Log},Greater]
```

Please be aware that

1. Each Symbol in the list are going to be evaluated twice, once for checking if it's numeric, and then for sorting. That could be circumvented by storing the intermediate result before taking the NumericQ.  **Edit** Thinking again, I'm not quite sure ... perhaps someone else can clarify on this one.
2. An expression is considered a numeric quantity if it is either an explicit number or a mathematical constant such as Pi, or is a function that has attribute NumericFunction and all of whose arguments are numeric quantities. In most cases, NumericQ[expr] gives True whenever N[expr] would yield an explicit number.
3. By changing NumericQ for StringQ or whatever you want (or adding it as a parameter for sortN[], you may select the *Type* you want to force and sort.

Comment: so what function then? How can I write my own if there is none in Mma 7.0? Thanks!

Comment: @Qiang Posted an example in the Edit. Use sortN[] as you'd use Sort[]

Comment: you can avoid the "reconstruction" step in sortN as follows (ignoring  evaluation leaks for simplicity):
sortN[s_, f_: (OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &)] :=
  Sort[s, f] /; And @@ (NumericQ /@ s)

Comment: @WReach That is a real improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case `Greater` fails to evaluate, and `Sort` seems to treat unevaluated comparison function as if it were evaluting to `True`, ie the following give the same result

```
Sort[{a, c, d}, True &]
Sort[{a, c, d}, UndefinedFunction&]
```

As to why, it depends on the internals, here's an example how it could happen

```
If[!compare[a,b],swap[a,b],dontswap[a,b]]
```

You see that `compare` evaluating to `True` and not evaluating has the same effect. In general, boolean expression evaluating to anything besides `True` or `False` can give unpredictable results, so you need to make sure your boolean values get evaluated.

Here's another example of [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181470/custom-function-with-non-standard-evaluation-behaves-like-table/4212982#4212982) that was caused by this issue

Comment: I think the reason of this behavior of Sort is that it helps stabilizing sorting when the comparison function is not reliable.